# Development Assets

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

In an App target, I can specify development assets to exclude from release builds.

Is this also possible with Swift packages?

I have SwiftUI views in a package and I want to preview an image asset, but I don't want that image to be shipped in the parent App target that consumes the package.

Comment: Using SPM for UI is generally a bad idea at the moment IMO. This bug pretty much makes it too tricky to be worthwhile https://forums.swift.org/t/xcode-previews-swiftpm-resources-xcpreviewagent-crashed/51680

Comment: And this one https://forums.swift.org/t/swiftui-previewer-crashes-while-in-swift-package-that-depends-on-anothers-packages-bundle-module-reference/41736

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2023, there apparently is no support for development resource files in Swift packages. I found this related thread on the Swift.org forum:

https://forums.swift.org/t/preview-assets-in-swift-package/63716